# Is there any functional or correct way to parse decimal number as exponential

Tags: c#, performance, decimal, exponential

I am trying to *parse* **C#** `decimal` type to *my own* `Decimal` type which has `significant` and `exponent` only. I tried this:

```
    public static MyType.Decimal FromDecimal(decimal decimalValue)
    {
        decimal tempValue = decimalValue;
        int exponent = 0;

        while ((long) (tempValue) < decimalValue)
        {
            tempValue *= 10;
            decimalValue *= 10;
            exponent--;
        }

        return new MyType.Decimal()
        {
            Significand = (long)tempValue,
            Exponent = exponent
        };
    }

    public class Decimal
    {
        public long Significand;
        public int Exponent;
    }
```

but in my opinion, it *will be slow*.

Comment: Why not use the built-in `decimal` that _also_ stores the significant digits and the exponent. What are you trying to gain that makes performance a consideration?

Comment: `but in my opinion, it will be slowly`  I think you didn't finish asking your question.  It will be slowly what?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You might also look at [`decimal.GetBits()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @DStanley Server side using this type of decimal, with Protogen serialization

Comment: Be careful with `long Significand`, since `decimal` uses **96-bit**, not **64-bit** (`long`) mantissa

Answer (score 0):

You can try [decimal.GetBits()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netframework-4.8), e.g.

```
  public static MyType.Decimal FromDecimal(decimal decimalValue) {
    int[] parts = decimal.GetBits(decimalValue);

    int sign = 1 - 2 * (parts[3] >> 31 & 1);
    long mantissa = ((((long)parts[1]) << 32) | (((long)parts[0]))) * sign;
    int exponent = -((parts[3] >> 16) & 0xFF);

    return MyType.Decimal() {
      Significand = mantissa, 
      Exponent    = exponent
    };
  }
```

But be careful: `decimal` uses **96-bit** mantissa (please, note, *abscence* of `parts[2]` which we *ignored*), that's why `long Significand` is *too short* (`long` is **64-bit** only)

**Demo:**

```
  decimal[] tests = new decimal[] {
    0m,
    10m,
    100m,
    0.01m,
    123e-1m,
   -3m,
    123456789e4m,
    123456789e-4m,
    1234567890123456m,
    1234567890123456e4m // 12345678901234560000 > long.MaxValue (9223372036854775807)
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => {
      int[] parts = decimal.GetBits(test);

      int sign = 1 - 2 * (parts[3] >> 31 & 1);
      long mantissa = ((((long)parts[1]) << 32) | (((long)parts[0]))) * sign;
      int exponent = -((parts[3] >> 16) & 0xFF);

      return $"{test,20} == {mantissa}e{exponent}";
    }));
```

**Outcome:**

```
                   0 == 0e0
                  10 == 10e0
                 100 == 100e0
                0.01 == 1e-2
                12.3 == 123e-1
                  -3 == -3e0
       1234567890000 == 1234567890000e0
          12345.6789 == 123456789e-4
    1234567890123456 == 1234567890123456e0
12345678901234560000 == -350295040e0        -- mantissa is 96 bit, doesn't fit 64-bit long
```